# Tools to measuring clients page rendering time in react-native app

Tags: performance, react-native, testing, tracking, event-tracking

I have a react-native mobile app and i want to measure the time it takes to render each page in client side of the app. (Ex- time that takes to login,Time that take to navigate one page to another). I want to track the time it takes in each event in client side. what are the tools that i can use for this scenario.

Comment: Are you looking to adopt someone's toolkit, or did this begin by trying to look at a certain problem (and you've already used some code, but you wanted something more off the shelf?)

Comment: What i understand is you are looking Performance testing Tool. If Yes? then for open Source Tool you can go for Apache Jmeter, or a Licensed tool such as HPE loadrunner.

Comment: @VishalCruise Im not looking for performance testing tool. lest say i have app installed on my mobile.i have to take the page rendering times of that application.(Ex:-If there are 2 pages page1 and page2.i want to navigate to page 1 to 2.what i want is calculate the time that takes to navigate page 1 to page 2) . Just want to check the page rendering time.